# Stuck at importing data directly from the staging machine to the development machine in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

My development database is exactly similar to the staging (and production) database. Table by table, field by field.

I know that I can use this command to connect to the remote database:

```
mysql -u user -p'password' -h host -P port -D database
```

And I can connect to my staging database easily and query data.

I also [read here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/copying-databases.html) that you can ssh to the remote machine and copy data to another machine.

But that is impossible for me because my development machine does not have a valid static IP address.

Also, I don't want to dump files on the staging machine, zip them, download them locally, and then import them. That's too many steps and its automation is hard.

I'm stuck at this point and I can't find anything by searching.

I want to use `mysql` + `mysqldump` (or `mariadb` + `mariadbdump`) to connect to the staging server directly and import data directly into my local development database.

How can I do that?

Comment: `mysql + mysqldump` cannot transfer the data directly, it uses intermediate dump file.

Comment: @Akina, but in the official documentation we have this command: `mysqldump db_name | mysql -h 'other_hostname' db_name`. There is no dump file in this command.

Comment: There is no **explicit** dump file - this is true. But check the disk size consumption during this process...

Comment: @Akina, my databases are very small. We are a website design agency. Our production databases never go beyond 100 megabytes in size. And the average size is below 50 megabytes. Thus it's not a concern. That's why I want to do it directly.

Comment: If the structure is absolutely similar then I'd prefer to create a script which will attach to remote server and copy the data from its tables with common INSERT INTO SELECT * FROM. I'd use [FEDERATED storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) for remote tables. Of course this needs in create this script file, but this must be done once.

Comment: @Akina, that would be perfect. I will read the link. But can you provide a simple example too?

Comment: The Reference Manual provides example statements. Read all subarticles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source machine:

```
mysqldump ... | mysql -h dest ...
```

Or, from the destination machine:

```
mysqldump -h source ... | mysql ...
```

Either tool (mysql or any dumper) can reach into the "other" machine.  The "dump file" does not need to exist since you can "pipe" from the dumper to the loader.

Caveat:  Some network situations may not allow one direction or the other -- For example, your local machine behind a NAT and the other in the Cloud.